# How often do supply drops drop?

Tags: the-division

In The Division as of the 1.1 "Incursions" update we receive supply drops within the DZ.

How often do these supply drops happen within a 24 hour period? Or is it completely random?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubisoft official release notes only say:

> Supply drops will occur multiple times over the course the day

However, according to the numerous sources<sup>[1](http://kotaku.com/the-divisions-endgame-is-about-to-get-a-lot-of-new-stuf-1768308934) [2](http://gaming.trendolizer.com/2016/04/the-division-dark-zone-is-getting-hourly-supply-drops-and-guaranteed-high-end-loot.html) [3](http://www.gamesradar.com/division-dark-zone-supply-drops-high-end-loot/)</sup> the drops are **hourly**, though I'm not sure if that actually means exactly once every 60 minutes. 
Playing for about 2h in DZ I've seen two supply drops.

Update: 
It seems to be at different times for different DZ servers. I managed to see 3 different drops in span of just half an hour on 3 different DZ servers (you get switched when joining friends on other servers).

Comment: No reason to think you're wrong, but can you link or cite any of "the numerous sources"?

Comment: @DCShannon  http://kotaku.com/the-divisions-endgame-is-about-to-get-a-lot-of-new-stuf-1768308934 http://gaming.trendolizer.com/2016/04/the-division-dark-zone-is-getting-hourly-supply-drops-and-guaranteed-high-end-loot.html http://www.gamesradar.com/division-dark-zone-supply-drops-high-end-loot/